# Slow Query only for specific values in a Where IN Clause

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if anyone has come across this behaviour before in the following query if I filter on "i.InspectionTypeID IN (x)" if x results in a large number (like about 2/3 of the entire result set of about 600 000) It takes a significantly longer amount of time to return even no results (15-30 seconds vs instantly otherwise).  I can include the query and the execution plans if that helps.  I can see a few differences between the queries but no idea how to refactor to improve it.  We have indexes around the place that should (and have) improved performance in other places but I seem to be stuck on this one.  Indexes don't appear to affect performance.  At least what I tried.

Slow Query Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyBDgxSeO

EDIT: New Plan and Updated the Query as per advice from @charlieface

Here's the query:

```
declare @currentUserID int = 1018
declare @currentCompanyID int = 43
declare @status int = 0
declare @pageSize int = 2147483647
declare @pageNumber int = 1

                    
                    DECLARE @notPreferredAssetIDsTable TABLE (id INT)
                    INSERT INTO @notPreferredAssetIDsTable
                    SELECT RecordID FROM SettingList sl 
                    WHERE SettingID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Setting 
                                        WHERE SystemUserID = @currentUserID AND Name = 'Preferred Assets' AND Status = @status)
                    AND Value = '0'
                    AND Status = @status 
                    SELECT i.ID As ID, a.AssetTypeID, at.Name as AssetTypeName, a.Code as AssetCode, a.Name as AssetName, CASE WHEN sections.SectionCount = 1 THEN cr.SectionName ELSE '' END as SectionName, c.Name as ContractName, reg.Name as RegionName, i.Carriageway, 
                           startStatus.StatusDate as StartDate, startPoint.Name as StartPointName, i.ChainageFrom, 
                           CASE WHEN i.Carriageway IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE i.ChainageFrom - (CASE WHEN i.Carriageway = 0 THEN startPoint.Forward ELSE startPoint.Reverse END) END StartDistancePast,
                           completedStatus.StatusDate As EndDate, endPoint.Name as EndPointName, i.ChainageTo,
                           CASE WHEN i.Carriageway IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE i.ChainageTo - (CASE WHEN i.Carriageway = 0 THEN endPoint.Forward ELSE endPoint.Reverse END) END EndDistancePast,
                               CASE WHEN i.Carriageway IS NULL THEN '' ELSE (CASE WHEN (ISNULL(OtherDirectionInspection.ID, 0) > 0) THEN 'Forward/Reverse'
                                                                                  WHEN i.Carriageway = 0 THEN 'Forward' ELSE 'Reverse' END) END as CarriagewayName,
                           dbo.GetInspectionTypeNamesForInspectionID(i.ID) AS InspectionTypeName, JobCount.Total As JobCount, i.CreatedDate, 
                           CreatedUserName.DisplayName as CreatedUserName, AssignedUserName.DisplayName as AssignedUserName,
                           i.Comments, i.EntireRoad, i.PlannedDate, latestStatus.InspectionStatus AS LatestInspectionStatus, completedStatus.StatusDate AS CompletedDate, it.CompanyID as InspectionTypeCompanyID, i.ContractID, i.InspectionTypeID, sections.SectionCount,
                           it.Category as InspectionTypeCategory, latestStatus.ModifiedDeviceID as DeviceID, latestStatus.ModifiedUserID as LatestStatusModifiedUserID, i.JobID, i.CapitalWorkID, cw.Name as CapitalWorkName, AssignedUser.Name as AssignedUserEmail, 
                           InspectionRouteName.Name as InspectionRouteName, i.InspectionGroupID,
                           il.Location AS InspectionLocation, 
                           i.OtherDirectionInspectionID , CustomText1 , CustomBit1 , CustomDate1 , CustomNumber1 , CustomReferenceItemID1 , CustomText2 , CustomBit2 , CustomDate2 , CustomNumber2 , CustomReferenceItemID2 , CustomText3 , CustomBit3 , CustomDate3 , CustomNumber3 , CustomReferenceItemID3 , CustomText4 , CustomBit4 , CustomDate4 , CustomNumber4 , CustomReferenceItemID4 , CustomText5 , CustomBit5 , CustomDate5 , CustomNumber5 , CustomReferenceItemID5 , CustomText6 , CustomBit6 , CustomDate6 , CustomNumber6 , CustomReferenceItemID6 , CustomText7 , CustomBit7 , CustomDate7 , CustomNumber7 , CustomReferenceItemID7 , CustomText8 , CustomBit8 , CustomDate8 , CustomNumber8 , CustomReferenceItemID8 , CustomText9 , CustomBit9 , CustomDate9 , CustomNumber9 , CustomReferenceItemID9 , CustomText10 , CustomBit10 , CustomDate10 , CustomNumber10 , CustomReferenceItemID10 , CustomText11 , CustomBit11 , CustomDate11 , CustomNumber11 , CustomReferenceItemID11 , CustomText12 , CustomBit12 , CustomDate12 , CustomNumber12 , CustomReferenceItemID12 , CustomText13 , CustomBit13 , CustomDate13 , CustomNumber13 , CustomReferenceItemID13 , CustomText14 , CustomBit14 , CustomDate14 , CustomNumber14 , CustomReferenceItemID14 , CustomText15 , CustomBit15 , CustomDate15 , CustomNumber15 , CustomReferenceItemID15 , CustomText16 , CustomBit16 , CustomDate16 , CustomNumber16 , CustomReferenceItemID16 , CustomText17 , CustomBit17 , CustomDate17 , CustomNumber17 , CustomReferenceItemID17 , CustomText18 , CustomBit18 , CustomDate18 , CustomNumber18 , CustomReferenceItemID18 , CustomText19 , CustomBit19 , CustomDate19 , CustomNumber19 , CustomReferenceItemID19 , CustomText20 , CustomBit20 , CustomDate20 , CustomNumber20 , CustomReferenceItemID20 , CustomText21 , CustomBit21 , CustomDate21 , CustomNumber21 , CustomReferenceItemID21 , CustomText22 , CustomBit22 , CustomDate22 , CustomNumber22 , CustomReferenceItemID22 , CustomText23 , CustomBit23 , CustomDate23 , CustomNumber23 , CustomReferenceItemID23 , CustomText24 , CustomBit24 , CustomDate24 , CustomNumber24 , CustomReferenceItemID24 , CustomText25 , CustomBit25 , CustomDate25 , CustomNumber25 , CustomReferenceItemID25 , CustomText26 , CustomBit26 , CustomDate26 , CustomNumber26 , CustomReferenceItemID26 , CustomText27 , CustomBit27 , CustomDate27 , CustomNumber27 , CustomReferenceItemID27 , CustomText28 , CustomBit28 , CustomDate28 , CustomNumber28 , CustomReferenceItemID28 , CustomText29 , CustomBit29 , CustomDate29 , CustomNumber29 , CustomReferenceItemID29 , CustomText30 , CustomBit30 , CustomDate30 , CustomNumber30 , CustomReferenceItemID30 , CustomText31 , CustomBit31 , CustomDate31 , CustomNumber31 , CustomReferenceItemID31 , CustomText32 , CustomBit32 , CustomDate32 , CustomNumber32 , CustomReferenceItemID32 , CustomText33 , CustomBit33 , CustomDate33 , CustomNumber33 , CustomReferenceItemID33 , CustomText34 , CustomBit34 , CustomDate34 , CustomNumber34 , CustomReferenceItemID34 , CustomText35 , CustomBit35 , CustomDate35 , CustomNumber35 , CustomReferenceItemID35 , CustomText36 , CustomBit36 , CustomDate36 , CustomNumber36 , CustomReferenceItemID36 , CustomText37 , CustomBit37 , CustomDate37 , CustomNumber37 , CustomReferenceItemID37 , CustomText38 , CustomBit38 , CustomDate38 , CustomNumber38 , CustomReferenceItemID38 , CustomText39 , CustomBit39 , CustomDate39 , CustomNumber39 , CustomReferenceItemID39 , CustomText40 , CustomBit40 , CustomDate40 , CustomNumber40 , CustomReferenceItemID40 , CustomText41 , CustomBit41 , CustomDate41 , CustomNumber41 , CustomReferenceItemID41 , CustomText42 , CustomBit42 , CustomDate42 , CustomNumber42 , CustomReferenceItemID42 , CustomText43 , CustomBit43 , CustomDate43 , CustomNumber43 , CustomReferenceItemID43 , CustomText44 , CustomBit44 , CustomDate44 , CustomNumber44 , CustomReferenceItemID44 , CustomText45 , CustomBit45 , CustomDate45 , CustomNumber45 , CustomReferenceItemID45 , CustomText46 , CustomBit46 , CustomDate46 , CustomNumber46 , CustomReferenceItemID46 , CustomText47 , CustomBit47 , CustomDate47 , CustomNumber47 , CustomReferenceItemID47 , CustomText48 , CustomBit48 , CustomDate48 , CustomNumber48 , CustomReferenceItemID48 , CustomText49 , CustomBit49 , CustomDate49 , CustomNumber49 , CustomReferenceItemID49 , CustomText50 , CustomBit50 , CustomDate50 , CustomNumber50 , CustomReferenceItemID50 
                    FROM Inspection i
                    INNER JOIN InspectionType it On i.InspectionTypeID = it.ID
                    INNER JOIN SystemUser CreatedUser On CreatedUser.ID = i.CreatedUserID 
                    INNER JOIN Contract c On i.ContractID = c.ID
                    INNER JOIN Region reg On c.RegionID = reg.ID
                    INNER JOIN InspectionLocation il ON il.InspectionID = i.ID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset a On i.AssetID = a.ID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN SystemUser AssignedUser On AssignedUser.ID = i.AssignedUserID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Road r On i.RoadID = r.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetType at On it.AssetTypeID = at.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Point startPoint On i.StartPointID = startPoint.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Point endPoint On i.EndPointID = endPoint.ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CapitalWork cw On i.CapitalWorkID = cw.ID
                    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNameForUser_Inline(i.CreatedUserID, i.ContractID, @currentCompanyID, 0) As CreatedUserName
                    OUTER APPLY dbo.GetNameForUser_Inline(i.AssignedUserID, i.ContractID, @currentCompanyID, 0) As AssignedUserName
                    OUTER APPLY 
                    (
                         SELECT TOP 1 SectionName
                         FROM ContractRoad cr
                         WHERE cr.RoadID = r.ID
                         AND cr.ContractID = i.ContractID
                         AND ((i.Carriageway = 0 AND i.ChainageFrom < cr.ChainageToForward AND cr.ChainageFromForward < i.ChainageTo)
                            OR (i.Carriageway = 1 AND i.ChainageFrom < cr.ChainageFromReverse AND cr.ChainageToReverse < i.ChainageTo))
                         AND cr.Status = @status
                    ) cr
                    OUTER APPLY 
                    (
                         SELECT count(SectionName) as SectionCount
                         FROM ContractRoad cr
                         WHERE cr.RoadID = r.ID
                         AND cr.ContractID = i.ContractID
                         AND ((i.Carriageway = 0 AND i.ChainageFrom < cr.ChainageToForward AND cr.ChainageFromForward < i.ChainageTo)
                            OR (i.Carriageway = 1 AND i.ChainageFrom < cr.ChainageFromReverse AND cr.ChainageToReverse < i.ChainageTo))
                         AND cr.Status = @status
                    ) sections
                    OUTER APPLY
                    (
                         SELECT TOP 1 StatusDate, LocalTime.LocalTime as StatusDateLocal
                         FROM InspectionStatus
                         CROSS APPLY tzdb.UtcToLocal_Inline(StatusDate, 'Australia/Sydney') as LocalTime
                         WHERE Status = @status
                         AND InspectionID = i.ID
                         AND InspectionStatus = 1
                         ORDER BY StatusDate
                    ) startStatus
                    OUTER APPLY
                    (
                         SELECT TOP 1 StatusDate, LocalTime.LocalTime as StatusDateLocal
                         FROM InspectionStatus
                         CROSS APPLY tzdb.UtcToLocal_Inline(StatusDate, 'Australia/Sydney') as LocalTime
                         WHERE Status = @status
                         AND InspectionID = i.ID
                         AND InspectionStatus = 5
                         ORDER BY StatusDate
                    ) completedStatus
                    OUTER APPLY
                    (
                         SELECT TOP 1 ID, StatusDate, InspectionStatus, ModifiedDeviceID, ModifiedUserID
                         FROM InspectionStatus 
                         WHERE Status = @status AND InspectionStatus.InspectionStatus <> 7
                         AND InspectionID = i.ID
                         ORDER BY CASE WHEN InspectionStatus.InspectionStatus = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, StatusDate DESC
                    ) latestStatus
                    OUTER APPLY
                    (
                         SELECT COUNT(ID) As Total FROM Job
                         WHERE InspectionID = i.ID
                         AND ParentJobID IS NULL
                         AND Status = @status
                    ) JobCount 
                    OUTER APPLY 
                    (
                         SELECT i2.ID 
                         FROM dbo.Inspection i2 
                         WHERE i2.OtherDirectionInspectionID = i.ID 
                         AND Status = @status 
                    ) OtherDirectionInspection
                    OUTER APPLY
                    (
                         SELECT TOP 1 ir.Name FROM InspectionRoute ir
                         INNER JOIN InspectionGroup ig ON ig.InspectionRouteID = ir.ID
                         WHERE ir.Status = 0
                         AND ir.CompanyID = 43
                         AND ig.Status = 0
                         AND ig.ID = i.InspectionGroupID
                    ) InspectionRouteName
                    
                    
WHERE i.Status = 0 AND i.ParentInspectionID IS NULL 
 AND il.Status = 0 
 --AND ((i.AssetID IS NOT NULL AND i.AssetID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @notPreferredAssetIDsTable)) OR i.AssetID IS NULL) 
 AND it.Category <> 2 
 AND c.IsArchived = 0 
 AND it.AssetTypeID = 3 AND a.AssetTypeID IS NOT NULL AND a.AssetTypeID = 3
 AND i.InspectionTypeID IN (3)
 AND i.ContractID IN (90,118) 
 AND (latestStatus.InspectionStatus IN (5,6,1,2,3) OR completedStatus.StatusDate IS NOT NULL  OR latestStatus.InspectionStatus IS NULL)
 AND ((completedStatus.StatusDateLocal >= '2021-02-01 00:00:00' AND completedStatus.StatusDateLocal <= '2021-02-05 23:59:59') OR (i.PlannedDate >= '2021-02-01 00:00:00' AND i.PlannedDate <= '2021-02-05 23:59:59') OR (i.CreatedDate >= '2021-02-01 00:00:00' AND i.CreatedDate <= '2021-02-05 23:59:59' AND (latestStatus.InspectionStatus not in (6, 5) OR latestStatus.InspectionStatus IS NULL)))
 AND ((CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 43) OR (CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 1 
                                            AND i.ContractID IN (90,118)) OR (CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 79 
                                            AND i.ContractID IN (90)) OR (CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 80 
                                            AND i.ContractID IN (90)) OR (CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 81 
                                            AND i.ContractID IN (90)) OR (CASE WHEN i.AssignedUserID IS NULL THEN CreatedUser.CompanyID ELSE AssignedUser.CompanyID END = 82 
                                            AND i.ContractID IN (90))) 
ORDER BY ID 
                    OFFSET @pageSize * (@pageNumber - 1) ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY 
                    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: What differences are there in the query between your FAST and SLOW query plans?  It seems like the full query is not shown in each of them. It would be clearer if you called out separately the differences

Comment: The only difference is in the line towards the bottom of the query "AND i.InspectionTypeID IN (3)" when that 3 is any other value it is fast but for 3 it's slow.

Comment: So what is in the ```InspectionTypeID``` column?  What data type?  What distribution of values?   Is there a large percentage of values that are 3 compared to other values? Have you tried filtering on ```InspectionType.InspectionTypeID``` instead -  you have an ```INNER JOIN``` between the tables so it would be just as valid logically to filter there

Comment: Of course it's slow: it has to deal with a lot of rows, poor indexing and scalar functions. Points to think about **1.** Strip out any join and column you don't need. **2.** Convert scalar functions to inline TVF **3.** That `Asset` table needs normalizing int rows, you shouldn't have `CustomText`, `CustomText2` etc. **4.** Get rid of the key lookups, index scans and index spools with better indexing: use `include` columns where necessary **5.** Combine `InspectionStatus` lookups into one conditional aggregation subquery. **When you've done all that, return here with any further questions**

Comment: @MartinCairney It's an int data type and yeah there are about 2/3 of the values in that table that are 3.  I did try filtering on the joined table's foreign key, yeah.  It made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @DaleK Yeah ran out of comment space, but don't like writing multiple comments because people go at you before seeing the end

Comment: @Charlieface - all good general points, but doesn't explain why only with the value 3 as the predicate does it perform poorly.  Looking at the Query Plans - they are identical and look to have been created for the value of InspectionTypeID = 4. So the estimates for the plan are for aa much lower number of rows from that table and hence a poor plan for the case when it is 3 and reusing a sub-optimal plan. Short term - maybe include ```OPTION (RECOMPILE)``` while you work on rewiting the query as per @Charlieface suggestions

Comment: @MartinCairney Sorry, that's what I meant at the beginning: it has to deal with far more rows and has no efficient access. Good point, I missed the parameter sniffing. If it had efficient access then maybe it wouldn't be so bad though. First fix the query then let's see.